# Where to add the jdbc driver on Netbeans/Glassfish in Windows?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, jdbc, glassfish

I have an enterprise app created in Netbeans 6.8 which comes packaged with a Glassfish V3 server. I've been receiving the following exception from the server log when I try to deploy and run the EAR project:

```
SEVERE: jdbc.exc_cnfe_ds
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

From googling, the common solution to this is to copy the jar file (mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar) containing that class to

```
$glassfish-v3-install-root/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib.
```

and in fact that's where it resides on the Unix server. However, I'm testing this on windows and the "domains/domain1" directories don't exist in the default glassfish install. I added them manually and added the jar, but it made no difference. I also added the jar as a variable to the windows classpath, but that also had no effect.

I then tried adding the jar file $glassfish-v3-install-root/glassfish/lib, and that produced a different error:

SEVERE: RAR5111 : Error casting to javax.sql.Datasource
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource

I'm using the same jar file as exists for the server. I'm guessing the jar is misplaced? I don't want to put it in the project because that's not how it's deployed in production. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the jar file in $glassfish-v3-install-root/glassfish/lib turned out to be correct.

The

```
"SEVERE: RAR5111 : Error casting to javax.sql.Datasource java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource"
```

error was, I believe, caused by an incorrect setting for the jdbc pooling on the glassfish server. But going to the admin console, available from the Netbeans "server" tab, going to the "JDBC", "Connection Pools", select "java.sql.driver" as the resource type and "com.mysql.jdbc.driver" as the driver classname will get rid of the casting issue.

Click the "Ping" button near the top to make sure you're connecting.